# Boxing The Entire Align Environment

Tags: align, boxes, multicol, enumitem

Here's my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\section{New Section}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=,leftmargin=0cm]
\item \[ \text{Example 1} \]

\begin{align*}
1 \\
2 \\
3
\end{align*}
\[ 123 \]
\item \[ \text{Example 2} \]

\begin{align*}
1 \\
2 \\
3
\end{align*}
\[ 123 \]
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Compiling it shows :

[image]

But I would like to box it like so :

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a **working** MWE. I think you forgot `\usepackage{enumitem} \usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: Sorry. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a `tabular*` instead of `multicols`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % or it would not stay
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc@{}}
  \textbf{Example 1} & \textbf{Example 2} \\
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \begin{center}
    $\begin{aligned}
    y & =ax+\dfrac{x^2}{b} & \text{Non-Linear} \\[1ex]
    \dfrac{y}{x} & =\dfrac{ax}{x}+\dfrac{x^2}{bx} \\[1ex]
    & =a+\dfrac{x}{b} & \text{Linear} \\[1ex]
    \dfrac{y}{x} & =\dfrac{1}{b}\cdot x+a \\[1ex]
    Y & =m\cdot X+c
    \end{aligned}$
    \end{center}
    Comparing the last two equations:
    \[ Y=\dfrac{y}{x},\quad m=\dfrac{1}{b},\quad X=x,\quad c=a \]
  \end{minipage}}
  &
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \begin{center}
    $\begin{aligned}
    y & =a\mathrm{e}^{bx} & \text{Non-Linear} \\
    \ln y & =\ln\left(a\mathrm{e}^{bx}\right) \\
    & =\ln a+\ln\mathrm{e}^{bx} \\
    & =\ln a+bx\ln\mathrm{e} & \text{Linear} \\
    \ln y & =b\cdot x+\ln a \\
    Y & =m\cdot X+c
    \end{aligned}$
    \end{center}
    Comparing the last two equations:
    \[ Y=\ln y,\quad m=b,\quad X=x,\quad c=\ln a \]
  \end{minipage}}
  \end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the constant “e” should be input as `\mathrm{e}`, not `\text{e}`, if you really want it upright (I see no reason for, but I'm a mathematician).

Comment: And you were faster than me---I used `tabularx` but think the answer is too similar to yours :)

Comment: Quick question. What does {\displaywidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc@{}} do? New to tabular here.

Comment: Strange. I got this instead : https://puu.sh/AXUL4/656c1124ac.png

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo Sorry, last minute change. Fixed.